# Recommended short (128 bit) and fast checksum for deduplication?

Tags: md5

I am using MD5 for file deduplication. This is great since the files are from a trusted source, and they will not intentionally exploit the MD5 shortcomings.

Later, I may accept untrusted files, and deduplicate them as well. I've read the summary of [MD5 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), and there seems to be many shortcomings in the quality of this hash. It is generally recommended to use SHA-1 or better.

SHA-1 & SHA-256 are longer. I could use XOR two halfs to reach a 128-bit answer, but that seems inefficient.

Is there a recommended 128-bit hash that fits the deduplication use case? I know it is so minor I could just continue using MD5, but seems another 128-bit alternative would have been developed by now?

Comment: What is your reasoning for wanting a 128-bit hash value? Does the hash feed into a de-duplication tool that only accepts 128-bit input?

Comment: If you are checking to see if a hash is already in a potentially large, ever-growing, set then that sounds like Bloom Filters.

Comment: @Mike, To reduce the length of the filenames. If lack of entropy was a concern (i.e. a large database of files), I would use a more robust hash. (similar to what fs deduplication systems use)

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with security, other than the fact that you're using functions similar to those which happen to also be used for security-related purposes. Sounds like more of an [so] question, and a little subjective at that.

Comment: @Iszi  There are attacks related to deduplication.  If attacker can preimage a find intended for deduplication he can cause the victim to either lose data or potentially be fed false information.  Most DD algorithms require the hash to be collision resistant in order to be secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just chop down SHA-256 or SHA-512 using the left 128 bits.  SHA-512 is actually 30% to 60% faster on 64 bit systems.  There is no reduction in security beyond the smaller digest length (128 bit digest = 128 bit strength against preimage and 64 bit strength against collisions).

Another option is SHAKE256.   NIST codified 4 fixed length drop in replacements for SHA-2 as SHA3-224, SHA3-256, SHA3-384, SAH3-512 but the underlying algorithm supports arbitrary bit lengths. The term SHAKE256 applies to the underlying algorithm being used for arbitrary sized outputs.  You could have a 128 bit or even 179 bit output using SHAKE256.

Still I would consider rehashing your file store using SHA-2 to get 256 bit identifiers while all the files are from trusted sources and then migration towards an all SHA-256 system prior to accepting potentially untrustworthy data.

Comment: I like the truncation of a widely used SHA hash rather than the less-prominent SHAKE. Thanks. Could you clarify: SHA-512 is faster than..SHA-256?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey For x64 systems yes.  SHA-512 works on 64 bit words and uses blocks 2x larger so it has higher throughput on 64 bit systems but slower throughput on x86 systems.  I agree with using SHA-2 over SHA-3.  Time is important.  In a decade or say SHA-3 should have the level of cryptanalysis that SHA-2 does now.